# The EU Refunds law and wether cost of download is refundable?

Tags: european-union

Under the [EU refunds law :](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/shopping/guarantees-returns/index_en.htm)  consumers have the right to get refund if the the product is faulty.Thus if someone distributes a faulty app which is free can the developer be asked for the cost of internet he(the user) bought to download the b h f app from play store and is this same for download of content m in other way.
I am asking this becaused it is outlined that si shipping cost of this purchase which in this case is the internet must be refundedd as stated [here](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/shopping/guarantees-returns/faq/index_en.htm) in questionno.5(spain one).**Basically must I refund the money of interenet connetion to download my free app?**
[image: explanatory image for eu refund]. 
                     **What is proof internet costs cannot be done refunded**

Comment: https://play.google.com/intl/en-us_us/about/play-terms/index.html google play store final purchase clause seems to rule out 14 day rule.

Comment: This is barely legible. [Please, improve this as told on Meta](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/how-do-i-improve-this-question)

Answer (score 3):

With respect to the two-year guarantee for faulty products, The [Consumer Sales Directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A01999L0044-20111212) does not apply to non-tangible products like softwares delivered by internet.

> (b) consumer goods: shall mean any tangible movable item, with the exception of:

Relevant rules on faulty digital services are contained in the [Digital Content Directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32019L0770), which provides

> 1. In the case of a lack of conformity, the consumer shall be entitled to have the digital content or digital service brought into conformity, to receive a proportionate reduction in the price, or to terminate the contract, under the conditions set out in this Article.
> 2. The consumer shall be entitled to have the digital content or digital service brought into conformity, unless this would be impossible or would impose costs on the trader that would be disproportionate, taking into account all the circumstances of the case including:
>    (a) the value the digital content or digital service would have if there were no lack of conformity; and
>    (b) the significance of the lack of conformity.

However, this is essentially irrelevant for free apps where no reduction of price is possible and it is likely an obligation to fix the app is disproportional given the price is zero.

Notably, the directive also puts most responsibilities regarding the "digital environment" (e.g. computers and network costs) on the consumer, as the environment is not particularly tied to the digital service.

---

In your comment, you refer to a 14-day rule. You might be confusing the guarantee laws with the cooling-off period provided by the [Consumer Rights Directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02011L0083-20180701).

In that case, you have a right of withdrawal but are only entitled to the costs you paid to the trader, and not any other third party, which is zero in the case of free apps. In an analogy to physical goods ordered online, you don't get a refund for your bus ticket if you need to go to the post office to collect it.

By the way, Google terms cannot override public law and in fact if you look into Google refund policy you'll see that EU laws are specifically mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer the bounty will be awarded by comunity votes.

Comment: My question was regarding the money spent to buy internet mm d f data  by the user.

Comment: @ask no, you cannot recover incidental costs involved in purchasing items, only direct costs you paid to the supplier.

Comment: Ok well I don't want to award bounty so fast but this is co rr ect .I think I overestimated EU requirements for developers.

Comment: How can you say for sure?

Comment: @ask because thats a cost the supplier doesnt have any say over at all, its a cost the recipient bears - not even the EU would put a supplier on the hook for someone downloading a 4K video over Immarsat satellite links and incurring tens of thousands of dollars of costs in the process....

Comment: Ok I heard f EU likes tg to defend customer so.

Comment: @ask theres a world of difference between defending the customer and creating a hostile business environment.

Comment: One last thing can Iask wether the customer must prove that the fault existed at time of rgdm operating the transmission of an app?

Comment: Is this yhe the same forb warrantuy f of accl accountability merchantibolity and habitability.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implied_warranty